# sparql query group by optional param

Tags: sparql, wikidata

**Query:** select instance of human whose profession is singer/musician

- wd:Q177220 (Singer)
- wd:Q639669 (Musician)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?human ?humanLabel ?genre ?genreLabel WHERE {
  VALUES ?professions {
    wd:Q177220
    wd:Q639669
  }
  ?human wdt:P31 wd:Q5;
    wdt:P106 ?professions;
    wikibase:statements ?statementcount.
  FILTER(?statementcount > 50 )
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
  OPTIONAL { ?human wdt:P136 ?genre. }
}
ORDER BY (?humanLabel)
LIMIT 50
```

[Query link](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fhuman%20%3FhumanLabel%20%3Fgenre%20%3FgenreLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fprofessions%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ177220%0A%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ639669%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fhuman%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5%3B%0A%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP106%20%3Fprofessions%3B%0A%20%20%20%20wikibase%3Astatements%20%3Fstatementcount.%0A%20%20FILTER%28%3Fstatementcount%20%3E%2050%20%29%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fhuman%20wdt%3AP136%20%3Fgenre.%20%7D%0A%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20%28%3FhumanLabel%29%0ALIMIT%2050)

How to group query by optional param genre so that it will return something like this *["rock", "pop-rock"]*

Comment: you#re not grouping by the genre but the `?human` of course. And then do `group_concat` for the genre

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ?human (sample(?humanLabel) as ?l) (group_concat(distinct ?genre; separator= ",") as ?genres) (group_concat(distinct ?genreLabel; separator= ",") as ?genreLabels) WHERE {
VALUES ?professions {
 wd:Q177220
wd:Q639669
 }
?human wdt:P31 wd:Q5;
wdt:P106 ?professions;
wikibase:statements ?statementcount.
FILTER(?statementcount > 50 )OPTIONAL { ?human wdt:P136 ?genre. }
SERVICE wikibase:label { 
bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". 
?genre rdfs:label ?genreLabel .
?human rdfs:label ?humanLabel .
}
}
group by ?human
ORDER BY (?humanLabel)
LIMIT 50`

Comment: @UninformedUser Im getting bad aggregate error when adding more optional param OPTIONAL { ?human wdt:P27 ?country_of_citizenship. }

Comment: for all non-grouping variables you have to apply some aggregate function, e.g. `sample` to get just one random value out of possible many or do `group_concat` to show all as a string. That's clearly what I did in my query.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance got it working. Thank you.